# Remove string (letters+underscore) inside parenthesis in php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to remove strings contained in parenthesis {}, but only if the string contain alpha numeric characters and underscores.

So the string:

> I'm a string. I have some {tags} that you have {to_remove}. But if you find function(){ alert('javascriptcode'); } you don't have to remove it.

Should become

> I'm a string. I have some  that you have . But if you find function(){ alert('javascriptcode'); } you don't have to remove it.

Comment: Are you doing this for some templating purpose?  If so, are you limited to using `{}` as opposed to something less likely to occur naturally like `{{{}}}`?  That being said, what attempts have you made so far?  can you show you code and explain what is not working?

Comment: [Regex Tester](http://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with the following Regex:

```
/\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\}/
```

Which will be something like:

```
preg_replace('/\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\}/', '', $yourText);
```

Comment: You need to escape `{` and `}` as they have a special meaning in a regex.

Comment: @jeroen You're right, but the code runs anyways. I'm curious why it runs without me escaping it, have you an explanation?